# Choose the highest combo

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, sorting

I am looking for a neat way to do the following but have a brain freeze:

User can add (and subsequently remove) a type to a shopping basket.
For each add or remove, I need to see if there is a type higher in the hierarchy that can be suggested instead. The highest type is preferable (**note** it has the same price as the penultimate type but b6 should be preferred over b5)

Examples:

```
2 x type1      (100+100) -> 1 x type2
type1 + type3  (100+300) -> 1 x type4
type3 + type4  (300+400) -> 1 x type6 + 1 x type2

1 type6 + 1 type2 + 1 type1 -> 1 x type6 + 1 x type3
```

and so on.

So if the total is 0, just add whatever is clicked.
If not, see if the total plus the new click can be resolved in a better combination starting from the top. If user declines the suggestion, ignore the add.

Code so far (tagged jQuery since the code is using it - map and filter are welcome)
I have not posted my attempts of the recalc, since I want to avoid the [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/udwYv/)

```
var types= { 
    b1: {price:100,quantity:0},
    b2: {price:200,quantity:0},
    b3: {price:300,quantity:0},
    b4: {price:400,quantity:0},
    b5: {price:500,quantity:0},
    b6: {price:500,quantity:0}
}
function getTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each(types,function(typeId,type) {
        total+=type.quantity*type.price;
    });
    return total
}
$(function() {
    var cont = $("#container");
    $.each(types,function(typeId,type) {
        $('<button class="add" id="'+typeId+'add">Add to '+typeId+'<button><span id="'+typeId+'val">0</button><button class="remove" id="'+typeId+'remove">Remove from '+typeId+'</button><span id="'+typeId+'total">0</span><br/>').appendTo(cont);
    });
    $(".add").on("click",function() {
        var id = this.id.replace("add",""),type=types[id];
        type.quantity++;
        var subTotal = type.quantity*type.price;
        $("#"+id+"val").text(type.quantity);
        $("#"+id+"total").text(subTotal);
        $("#total").text(getTotal());
    });
    $(".remove").on("click",function() {
        var id = this.id.replace("remove",""),type=types[id];
        if (type.quantity>0) type.quantity--;
        var subTotal = type.quantity*type.price;
        $("#"+id+"val").text(type.quantity);
        $("#"+id+"total").text(subTotal);
        $("#total").text(getTotal());
    });
});
```

Comment: So if a user clicks 'add b1' twice you want the result to show 0 for b1 and 1 for b2?

Comment: B6 and B5 have price of 500 both? Perhaps b6 should have price of 600(maybe typo from your side)? If not what do we choose then?

Comment: No alas not typo. B6 preferred.

Comment: Seems someone is on a downvote vendetta? This question is 4 years old and just voted down...

Comment: And again? What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little confusing what you are after. Try this:

```
//Sort the keys by price descending, and get the current total

   var remaining = getTotal(),
       keys = Object.keys(types).sort(function(a,b){
            return b.price > a.price ? -1 : 1;
       });


// Loop through the keys (sorted by price).
// Set quantity based on how many times the remainder goes into the price
// and update the remainder

    keys.forEach(
        function(k){
                var x = Math.floor(remaining/types[k].price);
                types[k].quantity = x;
                remaining -= x * types[k].price;
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GC3mW/

Answer (score 1):

The problem as you have described it sounds remarkably similar to the [coins-change algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

It can be made to work with a rather simple greedy loop, going somewhere along these lines:

```
while(total > 0) {
     total = total - [get largest price less than total]
     [increment amount for above largest price]
}
```

Here's your fiddle with that update: http://jsfiddle.net/DnRG9/1/

This doesn't handle any corner cases, so it's possible I've missed something. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Right - I actually have an old non trivial script I also outsourced that given a number of stamps and a postage will calculate the best fit. No longer useful in Holland. I just looked and your function looks remarkably like my first attempts. I was on the right track. I will see if it does all I need